# How can I fetch records from multiple tables

Tags: python, inheritance, optimization

I have one base model and multiple submodels which are inherited from base model.

```
class account(models.Model):
    ....common fields....
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class accounttypeA(account):
    .... specific fields....
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="typeA", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class accounttypeB(account):
    .... specific fields....
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="typeB", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class accounttypeC(account):
    .... specific fields....
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="typeC", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class accounttypeD(account):
    .... specific fields....
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="typeD", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Logged in user can create any number of account under any accounttype.
How can I fetch data from all tables ,using the user ID of the logged in user.
Put some inputs on this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `prefetch_related` in django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

```
user = Users.objects.prefetch_related('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC', 'typeD')
```

Let me know if this helps you.

If you want to extend this for logged in user then you can use this approach

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager


class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().prefetch_related('typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC', 'typeD').get(*args, **kwargs)


class YourUserModel(AbstractUser):
    ...

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Now in your `request.user` you will get these things.
I haven't tested the code, so please test this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I fetch only those records ,based on the logged in user Id?

Comment: @pd24 I have changed the code to handle logged in user